# Generate a polar heatmap on a semicircle from a csv file with three columns - python - matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, heatmap

I have been trying to generate a heatmap plotted on a semicircle.
The csv file I have has three columns.
column 1 is Temperature, column 2 is angle and column 3 is occurrence.

| Temperature | phiangle | Counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 0.71 | 4347 |
| 25 | 3.53 | 3149 |
| 25 | 4.94 | 2100 |
| 25 | 6.35 | 1731 |
| 25 | 7.76 | 1405 |
| .... | .... | .... |
| 249 | 172.94 | 3687 |
| 249 | 174.35 | 6592 |
| 249 | 175.76 | 12866 |
| 249 | 177.18 | 25725 |
| 249 | 180.00 | 23464 |

I have about 40K rows with temperature ranging from 25 to 249.

Now I would like the colorbar to show Counts (which is column 3).
I would like the phiangle (column 2 which changes only from 0 to 180) on a semi circle.
And temperature (column 1) to increase radially from the centre of the sphere.

Here is my code which does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

scsv = pd.read_csv('polarchartdata.csv', sep=";")

x = scsv['Temperature'].values
y = scsv['phiangle'].values
yrad = np.radians(y)
z = scsv['Counts'].values

print(scsv)
print(x,y,z)  

fig, axes = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
contourplot = axes.contourf(x, y, z)
axes.set_thetamin(0)
axes.set_thetamax(180)
plt.colorbar(contourplot, shrink=.6, pad=0.08)

plt.show()
```

I would want something similar with temperature going from the centre of the semicircle and outward.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Of course I would want to add a colorbar denoting the values in column 3.

When I Run this, I get a **TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 1D**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIM8v.png

Comment: "_Here is my code which does not work._" — what do you mean, it doesn't work? You get unexpected results (what?) or the program stops in error (then, post the complete backtrace)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @gboffi i get a type error: Input z must be 2D not 1D

Comment: Z needs to be 2d with its dimensions beeing that of x and y. So, if len(x) = N and len(y) = M, needs to be an array of NxM. If there are the same phiangles for each of your temperatures you would be able to reshape your data in a way that it fits contourf.